# expressJs default value of title variable declaration

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Where does express get the default value for its title variable. My index.jade looks like the following:

```
    h1= title
p Welcome to #{title}
```

I don't quite understand where the title variable is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `routes/index.js` you will be saying

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
```

So here it will find `views/index.jade` put value of `title` variable as `'Express'`.

You can say in your jade

```
p Welcome to #{title} from #{name}
```

and while renderring

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' ,name: 'myName'});
```

it will be converted in `Welcome to Express from myName`.

Comment: Got it. That made perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

In express, the template (.jade for example) has access to

- anything in `app.locals` which are basically global variables
- anything in `res.locals` which are tied to the request/response cycle of the current request
- anything passed to it via res.render() which will have typically been determined in your request route handler

Just to expand on this, here is an example that should demonstrate:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
    //set a global variable that will be available to anything in app scope
app.locals.globalVar = "GLOBAL";
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
//register a middleware that will set a local variable on the response
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.resLocalVar = new Date();
    next();
});
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/:id', routes.index);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

index.js:

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id || "Nothing"
    res.render('index', { renderVar: id });
};
```

index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
 p I am a global variable with value: #{globalVar}
 p I am scoped to the current request/response with value: #{resLocalVar}
 p I am only set on the call to render() in index.js and my value is: #{renderVar}
```

When you visit `http://localhost:3000/[some value]` you will see the values of `app.locals.globalVar`, `res.locals.resLocalVar`, and also the value of `renderVar` that's defined in the call to res.render() in index.js.

Answer (score 2):

You can set view variables at the [app level](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.locals), the [response level](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.locals), and/or [at the time of render](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render).